# LNK1181 on non-used file openssl/librtmp

Tags: c++, visual-c++, openssl, win-universal-app, rtmp

I am building an universal windows app in c++, in which I'm using [librtmp](https://rtmpdump.mplayerhq.hu/librtmp.3.html). I worked through a load of error messages, but I can't solve one of them:

```
LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib.obj'
```

I did a <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> on the entire project, and I couldn't find a reference to lib.obj anywhere, so I don't know where this file is linked in. I checked if the additional dependencies were set correctly, without quotation marks, which was the case.

I also tried running the linking process with the /verbose flag, but that didn't return any useful information:

```
1>
1>  Starting pass 1
1>LINK : fatal error LNK1181: cannot open input file 'C:\OpenSSL-Win64\lib.obj'
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve this problem, or any pointers on how to diagnose the linking process better?

Answer (score 0):

The vc++ linker is *quite* verbose when the /verbose switch is turned on. From what you get as a response, it hasn't even started to search libraries for the obj. This means that the obj file is part of the input, directly on the linkers command line.

Check the "CommandLine" properties for the given obj (Maybe it sneaks in there in the form of some kind of macro?). Also, make sure you are not inheriting some "Additional dependencies" from another configuration. Also, make sure you checked the "Additional dependencies" for the configuration/platform set that you are building.

Also, under Tools -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> Build and Run, turn up the verbosity of the msbuild output. This way you also get the actuall commands passed to the various tools. (This is basically the content from the response files.) The obj you are looking for must end up in that somehow and turning up the verbosity should give you a handle to find out where it's actually coming from.

Comment: I checked the linker command line, and lib.obj never appeared there. The result of building with maximum verbosity is visible here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/q3pubuc0s4vbv59/Output-Build.txt?dl=0